# Problems configuring ts-jest with package dependencies in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, monorepo

I am having problems with configuring ts-jest in a monorepo with packages that depend on each other. Things work great with esbuild and tsc but not with jest and ts-jest.

I am able to get all the basics working with moduleNameMapper, etc. Each package has its own tests and it's own jest configuration in the package's package.json. Tests that import only files from their own package work great. Tests that have cross package dependencies are where the problems arise.

In specific, the problem I'm having is if two different packages have the same top level directory, like:

```
+ packages
  + packageA
    + utils/foo.ts
    + someCode.ts
    + tsconfig.json
  + packageB
    + utils/bar.ts
    + tsconfig.json
    + packageB.test.ts
```

When code in packageA does an  import 'utils/foo.ts' and code in packageB does an import 'utils/bar.ts', with esbuild and tsc, everything works out great.

The problem comes with ts-jest. If packageB.test.ts does an import of packageA/someCode.ts which does an import 'utils/foo'  no matter what I try, it always tries to resolve to packageB/utils/foo which does not exist.

The same situation with tsc and esbuild works correctly. If code in packageB imports code in packageA that does an import 'utils/foo', it correctly finds the file.

To be clear, tests that have cross package dependencies without similarly named top level directories (i.e. files not using a common directory name like utils) work great.

I wrote a custom jest resolver, and console logged all the paths and the filterPaths and from what I can tell, the jest custom resolver is never being asked to resolve utils/foo. It is asked to resolve packageA/someCode.ts (which is does fine) but there is never a request to resolve utils/foo.

Does ts-jest try to do its own module resolution outside of jest's resolver system? As far as I can tell ts-jest is also only looking at the tsconfig.json of packageB.test.ts. I would expect it to look at packageA/tsconfig.json when trying to transpile utils/foo.ts but I can put syntax errors in packageA/tsconfig.json and it appears ts-jest never tries to parse it.

Any thoughts as to how to run jest tests in a monorepo for cross package dependencies?